# django runserver gets killed

Tags: python, django, multithreading

When there are simultaneous ajax request sent to [runserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#runserver) its gets killed.

I know earlier it was single threaded, but [--nothreading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-nothreading) option says it is now `multithreaded by default.` Still, my runserver gets killed.

I am running on django==1.10 and python==2.7

How do I stop runsever from getting killed?
Or This is because of python's multithreading limitations?

Comment: Is there any error when the development server gets killed?

Comment: No, it just says `killed` and aborts the request received.

Comment: I guess this is not related to Python's multi-threading limitation. Here the web server needs multi-threading not an Python process.

Comment: how many requests you need to do to kill the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of trial and error, I found the way to stop runserver from getting killed.

[--nothreading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-nothreading) actually solved my problem automagically.

so final commands to run dev server is.

```
django-admin runserver 1.2.3.4:8000 --nothreading
```

or

```
python manage runserver 1.2.3.4:8000 --nothreading
```

Happy I am :-)

Comment: I doubt you would be happy with that solution at production. Would it not be better run it with multiple workers (processes) using other server, for example gunicorn.

Comment: @MichałPiotrStankiewicz of course, this solution is only for dev environment.